# Animating a UILabel background color when text change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a UITableView and I have layout some labels for its rows. When the values change in the  table (means text values changes inside the labels), I need to animate the UILabel's backgroundcolor( eg. Background color from red --> its original background color). Then users can clearly notice the values changed.

As far as I understand there are 2 parts.

1. Detecting the text change event.
2. Do the animation for some time duration.

Can someone please tell me how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *text;

This property's setter can be overwritten as following.

```
- (void)setText:(NSString *)value
{
   ///< copy this value to a member variable

   ///< send a notification about the text of UILabel was changed.
}
```

About the animation effect, maybe you can see the [QuartzCore framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreRefCollection/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004291).
It is useful for custom animation effect with CALayer class.